# From a list of lists to a single object

Tags: c#, .net

Long story short a user can have things in common with another user, but I don't what to show more than 4 main categories in common, only the first 4, the priority is the order in which the lists are added.

Below is my current approach, but I feel that this can be simplified, and maybe improve the time.

Any thoughts?

```
var user1 = await UserService.GetInfo(id, reqUserId);
var user2 = await UserInfoService.GetInfo(reqUserId, reqUserId);

// determine info
List<InfoItemVM> infos = new List<InfoItemVM>();
InfoVM info = new InfoVM();

infos.Add( new InfoItemVM { Name = "Projects", Data = user1.Projects.Intersect(user2.Projects).ToList() });
infos.Add( new InfoItemVM { Name = "Companies", Data = user1.Companies.Intersect(user2.Companies).ToList() });
infos.Add( new InfoItemVM { Name = "Schools", Data = user1.Schools.Intersect(user2.Schools).ToList() });
infos.Add( new InfoItemVM { Name = "Hobbies", Data = user1.Hobbies.Intersect(user2.Hobbies).ToList() });
infos.Add( new InfoItemVM { Name = "Locations", Data = user1.Locations.Intersect(user2.Locations).ToList() });
infos.Add( new InfoItemVM { Name = "Interests", Data = user1.Interests.Intersect(user2.Interests).ToList() });
infos.Add( new InfoItemVM { Name = "Stuff", Data = user1.Stuff.Intersect(user2.Stuff).ToList() });
infos.Add( new InfoItemVM { Name = "Things", Data = user1.Things.Intersect(user2.Things).ToList() });
infos.Add( new InfoItemVM { Name = "MyLists", Data = user1.MyLists.Intersect(user2.MyLists).ToList() });

// assign bullet classes to maximum 4 in info categories
int max = 0; int med = 0; int medsm = 0; int min = 0;
int count = 0;

foreach (var c in infos.Where(c => c.Data.Count != 0))
{
    count++;
    if (count > 4 && c.Data.Count != 0)
        c.Data.Clear();
}

foreach (var c in infos)
{
    int value = c.Data.Count;
    if (value > max)
    {
        med = max;
        medsm = max;
        min = max;
        max = value;
    }
    else if (value < max && value > med)
    {
        medsm = med;
        min = med;
        med = value;
    }
    else if (value < med && value > medsm)
    {
        min = medsm;
        medsm = value;
    }
}
for (int i = 0; i < infos.Count; i++)
{
    int value = infos[i].Data.Count;
    // Doing this in order to return an object
    switch (infos[i].Name)
    {
        case "Projects":
            info.Projects.Data = infos[i].Data;
            info.Projects.Bullet = value == max ? "big" : value == med ? "medium" : value == medsm ? "medium-small" : "small";
            break;
        case "Companies":
            info.Companies.Data = infos[i].Data;
            info.Companies.Bullet = value == max ? "big" : value == med ? "medium" : value == medsm ? "medium-small" : "small";
            break;
        case "Schools":
            info.Schools.Data = infos[i].Data;
            info.Schools.Bullet = value == max ? "big" : value == med ? "medium" : value == medsm ? "medium-small" : "small";
            break;
        case "Hobbies":
            info.Hobbies.Data = infos[i].Data;
            info.Hobbies.Bullet = value == max ? "big" : value == med ? "medium" : value == medsm ? "medium-small" : "small";
            break;
        case "Locations":
            info.Locations.Data = infos[i].Data;
            info.Locations.Bullet = value == max ? "big" : value == med ? "medium" : value == medsm ? "medium-small" : "small";
            break;
        case "Interests":
            info.Interests.Data = infos[i].Data;
            info.Interests.Bullet = value == max ? "big" : value == med ? "medium" : value == medsm ? "medium-small" : "small";
            break;
        case "Stuff":
            info.Stuff.Data = infos[i].Data;
            info.Stuff.Bullet = value == max ? "big" : value == med ? "medium" : value == medsm ? "medium-small" : "small";
            break;
        case "Things":
            info.Things.Data = infos[i].Data;
            info.Things.Bullet = value == max ? "big" : value == med ? "medium" : value == medsm ? "medium-small" : "small";
            break;
        case "MyLists":
            info.MyLists.Data = infos[i].Data;
            info.MyLists.Bullet = value == max ? "big" : value == med ? "medium" : value == medsm ? "medium-small" : "small";
            break;
        default:
            break;
    }
}
return Ok(info);


public class InfoVM
{
    public InfoItemVM  Projects { get; set; }
    public InfoItemVM  Companies { get; set; }
    public InfoItemVM  Schools { get; set; }
    public InfoItemVM  Hobbies { get; set; }
    public InfoItemVM  Locations { get; set; }
    public InfoItemVM  Interests { get; set; }
    public InfoItemVM  Stuff { get; set; }
    public InfoItemVM  Things { get; set; }
    public InfoItemVM  MyLists { get; set; }

    public InfoVM()
    {
        Projects = new InfoItemVM  { Data = new List<string>(), Bullet = "", Name = "" };
        PreviousCompanies = new InfoItemVM  { Data = new List<string>(), Bullet = "", Name = "" };
        Schools = new InfoItemVM  { Data = new List<string>(), Bullet = "", Name = "" };
        Hobbies = new InfoItemVM  { Data = new List<string>(), Bullet = "", Name = "" };
        Locations = new InfoItemVM  { Data = new List<string>(), Bullet = "", Name = "" };
        Interests = new InfoItemVM  { Data = new List<string>(), Bullet = "", Name = "" };
        Stuff = new InfoItemVM  { Data = new List<string>(), Bullet = "", Name = "" };
        Things = new InfoItemVM  { Data = new List<string>(), Bullet = "", Name = "" };
        MyLists = new InfoItemVM  { Data = new List<string>(), Bullet = "", Name = "" };
    }
}

public class InfoItemVM 
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public List<string> Data { get; set; }
    public string Bullet { get; set; }

    public InfoItemVM()
    {
        Data = new List<string>();
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you add `InfoVM` implementation?

Comment: @NikitaB sure, done

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Every single `case` has the same code, and it's easy to replace it.

We break it down into methods so that the code is more isolated and easier to debug (and test).

```
public void UpdateItem(InfoItemVM item, List<string> data, int max, int med, int medsm)
{
    int value = infos[i].Data.Count;
    item.Data = data;
    item.Bullet = value == max ? "big" : value == med ? "medium" : value == medsm ? "medium-small" : "small";
}

public void UpdateItem(InfoVM viewModel, InfoItemVM item, int max, int med, int medsm)
{ 
    switch (item.Name)
    {
        case "Projects":
            UpdateItem(viewModel.Projects, item.Data, max, med, medsm);
            break;
        case "Companies":
            UpdateItem(viewModel.Companies, item.Data, max, med, medsm);
            break;
        case "Schools":
            UpdateItem(viewModel.Schools, item.Data, max, med, medsm);
            break;
        case "Hobbies":
            UpdateItem(viewModel.Hobbies, item.Data, max, med, medsm);
            break;
        case "Locations":
            UpdateItem(viewModel.Locations, item.Data, max, med, medsm);
            break;
        case "Interests":
            UpdateItem(viewModel.Interests, item.Data, max, med, medsm);
            break;
        case "Stuff":
            UpdateItem(viewModel.Stuff, item.Data, max, med, medsm);
            break;
        case "Things":
            UpdateItem(viewModel.Things, item.Data, max, med, medsm);
            break;
        case "MyLists":
            UpdateItem(viewModel.MyLists, item.Data, max, med, medsm);
            break;
    }
}

public void UpdateItems(InfoVM viewModel, List<InfoItemVM> items, int max, int med, int medsm)
{
    foreach (var item in items)
    {
        UpdateItem(viewModel, item, max, med, medsm);
    }
}
```

Then this:

> ```
> for (int i = 0; i < infos.Count; i++)
> {
>     int value = infos[i].Data.Count;
>     // Doing this in order to return an object
>     switch (infos[i].Name)
>     {
>         case "Projects":
>             info.Projects.Data = infos[i].Data;
>             info.Projects.Bullet = value == max ? "big" : value == med ? "medium" : value == medsm ? "medium-small" : "small";
>             break;
>         case "Companies":
>             info.Companies.Data = infos[i].Data;
>             info.Companies.Bullet = value == max ? "big" : value == med ? "medium" : value == medsm ? "medium-small" : "small";
>             break;
>         case "Schools":
>             info.Schools.Data = infos[i].Data;
>             info.Schools.Bullet = value == max ? "big" : value == med ? "medium" : value == medsm ? "medium-small" : "small";
>             break;
>         case "Hobbies":
>             info.Hobbies.Data = infos[i].Data;
>             info.Hobbies.Bullet = value == max ? "big" : value == med ? "medium" : value == medsm ? "medium-small" : "small";
>             break;
>         case "Locations":
>             info.Locations.Data = infos[i].Data;
>             info.Locations.Bullet = value == max ? "big" : value == med ? "medium" : value == medsm ? "medium-small" : "small";
>             break;
>         case "Interests":
>             info.Interests.Data = infos[i].Data;
>             info.Interests.Bullet = value == max ? "big" : value == med ? "medium" : value == medsm ? "medium-small" : "small";
>             break;
>         case "Stuff":
>             info.Stuff.Data = infos[i].Data;
>             info.Stuff.Bullet = value == max ? "big" : value == med ? "medium" : value == medsm ? "medium-small" : "small";
>             break;
>         case "Things":
>             info.Things.Data = infos[i].Data;
>             info.Things.Bullet = value == max ? "big" : value == med ? "medium" : value == medsm ? "medium-small" : "small";
>             break;
>         case "MyLists":
>             info.MyLists.Data = infos[i].Data;
>             info.MyLists.Bullet = value == max ? "big" : value == med ? "medium" : value == medsm ? "medium-small" : "small";
>             break;
>         default:
>             break;
>     }
> }
> ```

Simply becomes:

```
UpdateItems(info, infos, max, med, medsm);
```

Of course, we can take one more step to cleaning this up by using a `Dictionary<string, InfoItemVM>`:

Take our `UpdateItem(InfoVM, InfoItemVM, int, int, int)` method (second one) from above and rewrite it as follows:

```
public void UpdateItem(InfoVM viewModel, InfoItemVM item, int max, int med, int medsm)
{ 
    var map = new Dictionary<string, InfoItemVM>
    {
        {"Projects", viewModel.Projects},
        {"Companies", viewModel.Companies},
        {"Schools", viewModel.Schools},
        {"Hobbies", viewModel.Hobbies},
        {"Locations", viewModel.Locations},
        {"Interests", viewModel.Interests},
        {"Stuff", viewModel.Stuff},
        {"Things", viewModel.Things},
        {"MyLists", viewModel.MyLists},
    };

    UpdateItem(map[item.Name], item.Data, max, med, medsm);
}
```

Comment: Hello, and than you for your interest. I think you meant `UpdateItem(map[item.Name], item.Data, max, med, medsm);` maybe

Comment: @SGN Yep, good catch.

Answer (score 8):

You should replace individual properties on `InfoVM` with a collection. Then you can use LINQ to build it:

```
var commonCategories = infos.Where(x => x.Data.Count > 0)
                            .Take(4)
                            .OrderBy(x => x.Data.Count);

var index = 0;                            
foreach(var category in commonCategories)
{
    category.Bullet = (BulletSize) index++;
    info.CommonCategories .Add(category);
}
```

where

```
enum BulletSize
{
    Small,
    MediumSmall,
    Medium,
    Large
}

public class InfoVM
{
    public ObservableCollection<InfoItemVM> CommonCategories { get; set; }

    ....
}
```

Comment: The problem with this is that the OP is required to replace the view model, which may not be possible in this scenario.

Comment: @EBrown, true. But this problem is not going away unless `InfoVM` is changed. Because current design *is* the problem.

Answer (score 1):

The Name property is too fragile
If an invalid Name is entered then lots of stuff breaks
You have a tight coupling to InfoItemVM properties

```
public class InfoItemVM 
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public List<string> Data { get; set; }
    public string Bullet { get; set; }

    public InfoItemVM()
    {
        Data = new List<string>();
    }
}
```

When you initialize you don't even give proper names

```
Projects = new InfoItemVM  { Data = new List<string>(), Bullet = "", Name = "" };
```